# How do I express these tests correctly with fluent assertions?

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I have the `record` type below.

```cs
public record CustomFormatGroupItem(string GroupName, string CfName, string CfAnchor);
```

I have a method that returns a collection of these, followed by two test assertions:

```cs
ICollection<CustomFormatGroupItem> result = sut.Parse();

result.Select(x => x.GroupName).Distinct()
    .Should().BeEquivalentTo(
        "Audio Advanced #1",
        "Audio Advanced #2",
        "Movie Versions",
        "Unwanted"
    );

result.Where(x => x.GroupName == "Audio Advanced #1").Select(x => (x.CfName, x.CfAnchor))
    .Should().BeEquivalentTo(new[]
    {
        ("TrueHD ATMOS", "truehd-atmos"),
        ("DTS X", "dts-x"),
        ("ATMOS (undefined)", "atmos-undefined"),
        ("DD+ ATMOS", "dd-atmos"),
        ("TrueHD", "truehd"),
        ("DTS-HD MA", "dts-hd-ma"),
        ("DD+", "ddplus"),
        ("DTS-ES", "dts-es"),
        ("DTS", "dts")
    });
```

I'm concerned with my usage of LINQ to massage the data into a format I can run a fluent assertions condition against. My understanding of the philosophy of Fluent Assertions is that you should basically not manipulate the data before comparing it. I know that FA provides a suite of methods that can be used to compare data in different ways, but I'm not sure if it can manipulate / test the data in the way I am above.

Basically I'm testing two different things:

1. In the whole collection, that exactly 4 distinct values appear in the property `GroupName` at least once (there may be duplicates, but that's OK)
2. For any elements whos `GroupName` property equals a specific value, a list of values is matched collectively against the `CfName` and `CfAnchor` properties.

This is sort-of like a dictionary of lists, but not exactly. So I can't use things like `ContainsKey()`, AFAIK. Is it inappropriate to be using LINQ the way I am here, and if so, how should I represent this better using Fluent Assertions to match its philosophy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid having to remove duplicates there's `BeSubsetOf`

```cs
result.Select(x => x.GroupName).Should().BeSubsetOf(new[]
{
    "Audio Advanced #1",
    "Audio Advanced #2",
    "Movie Versions",
    "Unwanted"
});
```

To avoid having to only select the `GroupName` property we can utilize that `BeEquivalentTo` uses the expectation to select the members to compare by.

```cs
result.DistinctBy(x => x.GroupName).Should().BeEquivalentTo(new[]
{
    new { GroupName = "Audio Advanced #1" },
    new { GroupName = "Audio Advanced #2" },
    new { GroupName = "Movie Versions" },
    new { GroupName = "Unwanted" }
});
```

There's nothing built-in in FluentAssertions to do both of the above, but we can create an extension method for that.

```cs
result.Should().OnlyContainEquivalentsOf(new[]
{
    new { GroupName = "Audio Advanced #1" },
    new { GroupName = "Audio Advanced #2" },
    new { GroupName = "Movie Versions" },
    new { GroupName = "Unwanted" }
});
```

```cs
internal static class GenericCollectionAssertionExtensions
{
    [CustomAssertion]
    public static AndConstraint<TAssertions> OnlyContainEquivalentsOf<TCollection, T, TAssertions, TExpectation>(
        this GenericCollectionAssertions<TCollection, T, TAssertions> parent,
        IEnumerable<TExpectation> expectations,
        Func<EquivalencyAssertionOptions<TExpectation>, EquivalencyAssertionOptions<TExpectation>> config,
        string because = "",
        params object[] becauseArgs)
            where TCollection : IEnumerable<T>
            where TAssertions : GenericCollectionAssertions<TCollection, T, TAssertions>
    {
        foreach (T subject in parent.Subject)
        {
            bool foundMatch = expectations.Any(expectation => 
            {
                using var scope = new AssertionScope();
                subject.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectation, opt => config(opt));
                string[] failures = scope.Discard();
                return failures.Length == 0;
            });
            
            Execute.Assertion
                .ForCondition(foundMatch)
                .BecauseOf(because, becauseArgs)
                .FailWith("Expected {context:collection} {0} to only contain equivalents of {1}{reason}, but {2} did not.", 
                    parent.Subject, expectations, subject);
        }

        return new((TAssertions)parent);
    }
    
    [CustomAssertion]
    public static AndConstraint<TAssertions> OnlyContainEquivalentsOf<TCollection, T, TAssertions, TExpectation>(
        this GenericCollectionAssertions<TCollection, T, TAssertions> parent,
        IEnumerable<TExpectation> expectations,
        string because = "",
        params object[] becauseArgs)
            where TCollection : IEnumerable<T>
            where TAssertions : GenericCollectionAssertions<TCollection, T, TAssertions>
    {
        return parent.OnlyContainEquivalentsOf(expectations, opt => opt, because, becauseArgs);
    }
}
```

For the second assertion in question, the only adjustment I see to make it use anonymous types like the second example above.

```cs
result.Where(x => x.GroupName == "Audio Advanced #1").Should().BeEquivalentTo(new[]
{
    new { CfName = "TrueHD ATMOS", CfAnchor = "truehd-atmos" },
    new { CfName = "DTS X", CfAnchor = "dts-x" },
    new { CfName = "ATMOS (undefined)", CfAnchor = "atmos-undefined" },
    new { CfName = "DD+ ATMOS", CfAnchor = "dd-atmos" },
    new { CfName = "TrueHD", CfAnchor = "truehd" },
    new { CfName = "DTS-HD MA", CfAnchor = "dts-hd-ma" },
    new { CfName = "DD+", CfAnchor = "ddplus" },
    new { CfName = "DTS-ES", CfAnchor = "dts-es" },
    new { CfName = "DTS", CfAnchor = "dts" }
});
```